# table locked or in use when calling RunSQL

Tags: ms-access

I have some code which re-arranges some items on a form, but only one SQL query.  All my tables aren't locked before the code runs but for some reason I get an error when running:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("Select * Into MasterTable From Year07 Where 'ClassName' = '7A'")
```

Error:

> The database engine could not lock table  because it is already in use by another person or process. (Error 3211)  To complete this operation, a table currently in use by another user must be locked. Wait for the other user to finish working with the table, and then try the operation again.

Any ideas what I can do to stop the table being locked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is MasterTable included in your form's Record Source?  If so, you can't replace it, or modify its structure, while the form is open.

Apart from the table lock issue, there is a logic error in the SELECT statement.

```
Where 'ClassName' = '7A'
```

The string, *ClassName*, will never be equal to the string, *7A*.  Therefore your SELECT can never return any records.  If ClassName is the name of a field in your Year07 table, discard the quotes which surround the field name.

```
Where ClassName = '7A'
```

Comment: Yes the MasterTable is in the form's record source.  Do you know how I can get around this without having to close the form, perform the action and then re-open the form?  I've also changed the 'ClassName' issue, although in an SQL datasheet view it didn't make a different.  Thanks again :)

Comment: My best guess is you should substitute `Select * From Year07 Where ClassName = '7A'` wherever MasterTable appears in your form's Record Source.  IOW, you may not even need MasterTable as an actual table.  But that is only my guess.  You may get a better guess if you edit your question to show us the Record Source.

Comment: The idea is to have many tables containing different data but to only display one at a time (chosen by a combo box).  When the combo box is changed, the values in the MasterTable change to show only what is needed.  I wasn't sure in access how to do this properly, but know now.  Thanks! :)

Comment: Huh. I misread this answer yesterday -- Hans says the same thing I do in his first paragraph and then quickly moves onto something else. In reading, the first part didn't register for me, or I never would have posted my own answer. +1

Comment: You said it better, David ... especially the point that Make Table queries don't belong in production applications.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing, but if you're using a form that is bound to MasterTable, you can't run a query to replace it with a new MasterTable while you've got it open in the form.

I would suggest that you get rid of the MakeTable query (SELECT INTO) and instead use a plain append query (INSERT). You'll want to clean out the old data before appending the new, though.

Basically, a MakeTable query is, in my opinion, something that does not belong in a production app, and any process that you've automated with a MakeTable query should be replaced instead with a persistent temp table that is cleared before the new data is appended to it.

Comment: +1 "a MakeTable query is, in my opinion, something that does not belong in a production app"

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this when you re-open a database after Access has crashed. Typically for me a reboot has fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

What version of MSAccess? Not sure about newer ones, but for Access 2003 and previous, if you were sure nobody was in the database, you could clear up locks after a crash by deleting the .ldb file.

Comment: It's access 2007.  I've tried deleted the .ldb but as soon as I open the original .accdb again I get the same problem.